What the benefit of PreloadAllModules if we applied lazy-loading?
As I understand, the benefit of lazy-loading it's reduce your bundle of network, and load the modules when we needed.
Issue:
Why in many articles say

It is best to use the PreloadAllModules strategy to load all modules at once, to eliminate any network delay.

Is that the opposite of the concept of lazy-loading?

I have read many articles about that, but I don't find answer.
Article 1
Article 2

without lazy loading at all - when you navigate to site.com/pagea you would download whole site (pagea, pageb, pagec....) and only then see the rendered "pagea". with lazy loading - you would only load pagea and that is it. with preloadAllModules, you would see "pagea", and then, when the process is idle you will preload other modules. As a result navigating pagea->pageb should be almost instant as pageb is "preloaded"

a small note: preloadAllModules will only load lazy ROUTES. it will not affect any other dynamic import()s in the application. there are webpack magic comments or other tools that allow to preload such things

The advantage of lazy loading is that, a group of element which are collectively called as module, are fetch only when there is a need for it (Just-In-Time), this had the advantage of decreasing the initial bundle size and website loads faster.
Sometimes, the lazy loaded modules, become too big, so that when you visit a route of the lazy loaded module, there is a significant delay for the page to load, to solve this we can use PreloadAllModules which will load the lazy loaded modules in the background.
Lazyloading is not the opposite of preloading, the opposite of lazy loading is eagar loading where we fetch all the modules at once ( large bundle size). Preloading is another layer of performance improvement when lazy loaded bundles become too big for the network to fetch it on time and user notices a delay!

Imagine you make a native mobile application like ionic capacitor do, the app must act like native, For example if user select an item from the list you must show the item details page that must be completely rendered and no need for user to wait and see a white page before loading the template.
